# VBA script go to infinite loop

Tags: excel, vba

i have small problem here where my vba not working as i code to. This process is to insert new row after last row in the existing sheet. But cell in the sheet is still empty before insert the data. Below is my code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim n As Integer

On Error Resume Next
n = InputBox("How many CTRs to be created?")
If n >= 1 Then
    For numtimes = 1 To n
        Sheet3.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                    
        If (numtimes > 30) Then
        Dim iter As Range
        Set iter = Cost_Sum.Range("B34")
        Do
            Set iter = iter.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop While iter.Value <= numtimes
        iter.EntireRow.Insert xlDown

        
        End If
        
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

This where the output after run the code.
[image]

but what i want is to continue insert row after last row CTR30.
Appreciate that you could help. thanks

Comment: Remove that `On Error Resume Next`, it's suppressing all the errors. Run again and see if there's any error (if yes, what error message and on what line)

Comment: It said runtime error '1004'.  Application-defined or object-defined error. got error at line
do loop Set iter = iter.Offset(1). this line error.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, what are the value from cell B34 onwards? Or rather, what are you trying to do for that code?

Comment: Step through the code and see what's the value/address of `iter` when the error occurs

Comment: i found that this method need a stopper to stop the loop. so at the NEXT numtimes to change the infinite loop. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by change few line to new code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim n As Integer

On Error Resume Next
n = InputBox("How many CTRs to be created?")
If n >= 1 Then
For numtimes = 1 To n
    Sheet3.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                
    Sheet5.Rows(7).Copy
    Sheet5.Rows(7 + numtimes).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    
Next numtimes
End If
End Sub
```